# Display database info into html table Wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, wordpress

I have the table called: persona, in my database. 
I just need to retrieved the data in this table into a html table inside a page in wordpress. SO far this is what i have:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM persona" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
        echo '<td>' $print->ID_per.'</td>';
        }
  ?>
</tr>
```

i added in the specific page i am working on and publish it but when i refresh the page it only shows the code printed in the page. I wonder if i am puting the code in the right place or i do not know where to put it.

Look at the images below:
[image]

Comment: you cannot put php code in any wordpress pages / post, you should  create a template and use it in your page.

Comment: Better yet would be to create a shortcode in your theme's functions.php file that would allow you to do this with a shortcode.

Comment: much better option! let me show you the code

Comment: @ArsalanMithani i just clone the page.php file and put that content, is that enough?

Comment: @ArsalanMithani yes please, how could i add this code into a function?

Comment: @cale_b thanks caleb, for ur response. SO i just need to add this code to the function? is that enough, nothing else to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your situation, the simplest, best way to do this would be to add a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to your theme.

If you add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file, you will then be able to display the information wherever you like by adding `[persona-table]` to any page or post.

```
// add the shortcode [persona-table], tell WP which function to call
add_shortcode( 'persona-table', 'persona_table_shortcode' );

// this function generates the shortcode output
function persona_table_shortcode( $args ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Shortcodes RETURN content, so store in a variable to return
    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '</tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Points</th></tr>';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( ' SELECT * FROM persona' );
    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content = '<tr>';
        // Modify these to match the database structure
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->firstname . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->lastname . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->ID_per . '</td>';
        $content .= '</tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

    // return the table
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: hey caleb! this solution worked. Just for somereason it is not taking the table style

Comment: no problem caleb i already fix that. What i want to do right now is to style the table, but if i add classes on elements this does not work:
$content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->ID_per . '</td>'; any suggestions? thanks in advanced

Comment: That's what you would do: `$content.= '<td class="rowtable">' ....` - but then you have to have your stylesheet loaded, and troubleshoot if / why your styles are not being applied.

Comment: when you say: "your stylesheet loaded", you mean load the style.css file in the function?

Comment: "Your stylesheet" - wherever you are adding the styles to style the table.  "loaded" meaning that you view source of your page and double-check that said stylesheet is in fact loading properly.  Or, use your browser console / inspector to inspect the element(s) to see if it's loading, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function db_short() {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM persona" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
        echo '<td>' $print->ID_per.'</td>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'show_db_info', 'db_short' );
```

And then you can just insert the shortcode [show_db_info] where you put the php code. If you want to further edit the php you are free to do so inside of this function. If you need different selections from your database you add shortcode attributes, but just for listing these this should be enough. This goes into functions.php

Comment: thank you for ur help @L L . i tried your suggestions but some reason the $print line gave me an error. thank u so much

Comment: I just wrote a quick snippet based off your code, @cale_b 's answer is much more complete and accurate. Good luck with your project!

Comment: but i appreciate your help LL , thanks though. have a nice day